# Show that if vertex cover has size k, then the treewidth of graph is at most k?

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that if vertex cover has size k, then the treewidth of graph is at most k

I can show an example that a graph which has a vertex cover of size k, then treewidth would be at most k. But how to prove it? Note that there are many variants of tree decompositions for graph G.

Details:
we are talking about tree decomposition. So, width of tree decomposition is $\max_{X_i \in X} X_i-1$ while treewidth of graph is minimum width of all tree decomposition.

let's give an example: suppose we have a tree graph: a-b-c-d. Now, we can put it in tree decomposition such as:

Tree decomposition 1: (ab)-(bc)-(cd), width here is 1

Tree decomposition 2: (abc)-(cd), width here is 2

Tree decomposition 3: (abcd), width here is 3

So, treewidth of this graph is 1. since 1 is the minimum width among all tree decomposition of graph a-b-c-d.

Now, how can I know that graph is tree decomposition? we check the the three following conditions:
1. all vertices in all bags. 
2. if $(u,v) \in E$, then (u,v) must be in one of the bags.
3. for all $v \in V$, then v in tree decomposition must form a single bag or subtree tree (but not a forest).

see more about tree decomposition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) also see the example in the wikipedia, it seems good!

Now about the question: Suppose I have complete graph of 4 vertices. Then vertex cover is 3. Now, if you try to construct tree decomposition of this graph, then you need to put all vertices in one bag; otherwise you will have cycle. So, size of bag is 4. And width will be 4-1=3 And since this is the best among all tree decompositions, therefore we have treewidth = 3.

Comment: Another condition for a tree decomposition is that if $B_1 \cap B_3 \subseteq B_2$ then $B_2$ must be on the unique path from $B_1$ to $B_3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph, $V$ be the set of its vertices, and a set $V_0\subset V$ of size $k$ constitutes a vertex cover of $G$. Let $v_1,\dots, v_r$ be the enumeration of the set $V\setminus V_0$. Consider a $k$-tree $H$ constructed as follows. Let $H_0$ be a complete graph on the vertex set $V_0$ and for each $i$ from $1$ to $r$ the graph $H_i$ is constructed from the graph $H_{i-1}$ by adding to it a vertex $v_i$ and connecting it with all vertices of $H_0$. Since $V_0$ is a vertex cover of $G$, $G$ is a subgraph of $H$.

Comment: (100+) Thank you so much! I did not understand it from first reading! Respect to you!

Comment: @user777 Thanks for your kind words. I guess that to deal with treewidth via $k$-trees is easily and clearly than using the tree decomposition, and this approach allows such brief proofs.